Detecting method of extension usage in php code
I'm now creating php extension for personal purpose and future developed projects. It must return a string as another function variable with specific name and thats all. But I want alter answer which it return if that extension was assigned as variable directly in print_r\file_put_contents\var_dump\echo, etc.
Is it possible from C-code side, inside extension code, detect in which statement it was called? Or maybe I must write another wrapper for all php code inside of file, which detects call of that extension and detects in which situation it was called?
Any help appreciated.
